# NameError - uninitialized constant ContactController

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to create a contact form to allow the user to contact the owner of the website but I got an error I can't get rid of ...

I got this error in my console :

> NameError - uninitialized constant ContactController:
>   Started POST "/__better_errors/e029756238b49ce0/variables" for ...

And this error in the local page :

> NameError at /contact.html
>   uninitialized constant ContactController

```
raise(e) unless e.name == const_name
            # If the constant was actually loaded, something else went wrong?
            raise(e) if from_mod.const_defined?(const_name)
            CoreExt::ActiveSupport.without_bootsnap_cache { super }
          end
```

with a highlight on `CoreExt::ActiveSupport.without_bootsnap_cache { super }`

I put that in my contacts_controller.rb :

```
class ContactsController < ApplicationController
    def new
        @contact = Contact.new
    end

    def create
        @contact = Contact.new params[:contact]

        if @contact.valid?
          ContactMailer.contact_form(@contact).deliver_now
          redirect_to contact_path, flash: {success: t(:"create.message_has_been_sent")}
        else
          render :new
        end
    end
end
```

I have that in my contact_mailer.rb :

```
class ContactMailer < ApplicationMailer
    layout 'mailer'

    def contact_form(contact)
      @contact = contact
      @to = "zigzago@protonmail.com"

      mail(to: @to, subject: "Nouveau contact depuis le site") do |format|
        format.html
      end
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Spot the difference - `ContactController` vs `ContactsController` (one plural, other is not)

If you have your routes set up this way so that controller has singular name - rename it (and the file) to match, or change routes.

Comment: Ok it's not working but I don't have the error anymore thanks :)